# Batch script not working due to spaces in file paths

Tags: batch-file, scripting, cmd, batch-processing

So I'm new to batch scripting and scripting in general. I recently made a script where files from a source directory will be organised according to its 'last modified date' into a destination directory.

Here's an extract of the script:

```
@echo off
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
echo Organise files
set /P _a="Enter source directory:"
set /P _b="Enter destination directory:"
set /P _c="Organise files by dd-mm-yyyy format (last modified)? y or n?" 
if %_c% == y goto:ddmmyy

:ddmmyy
for %%A in ("%_a%\*") do echo %%~tA %%~snA %%~xA >> "%_a%\testtoken.txt"
for /F "tokens=1-7* delims=./ " %%B in (%_a%\testtoken.txt) do (
robocopy "%_a%" "%_b%\%%B-%%C-%%D" "%%G.%%H" /xf testtoken.txt /mov
)
```

The script works just fine unless I use directories with spaces in their names (eg. C:\Program Files instead of C:\Program). I also had the same issue with spaces in file names until I used 8.3 notation, however using 8.3 notation results in other issues like robocopy not copying files with fairly similar names (eg. TUTORI~2, TUTORI~1, TUTORI~3 etc.)

Here's the format of testtoken.txt:

```
02/11/2014 06:02 PM SPSETU~1 .exe 
16/11/2014 09:19 AM TUTORI~4 .docx 
14/11/2014 12:00 PM TUTORI~2 .docx 
16/11/2014 09:19 AM TUTORI~3 .docx 
14/11/2014 12:00 PM TUTORI~1 .docx 
16/11/2014 09:19 AM TU44E0~1 .docx 
16/11/2014 09:19 AM TU05DE~1 .docx 
16/11/2014 10:59 PM UNIFYI~1 .pdf 
09/11/2014 07:55 PM ZOROAS~1 .jpg
```

So is there a way to make the script disregard the spaces? Why won't robocopy copy files with fairly similar names in 8.3 notation and is there any way to force robocopy to actually copy the files?

Comment: Where does PowerShell come into it here? I only see a batch file.

Comment: I only added for visibility because afaik powershell is similar to batch. I'll remove it now though

Comment: It's a completely different language with a slight overlap in purpose ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir\t w o"
SET "destdir=U:\destdir"
for %%A in ("%sourcedir%\*") do echo %%~tA %%~fA>> "%sourcedir%\testtoken.txt"
for /F "USEBACKQ tokens=1,2,3,5* delims=/ " %%B in ("%sourcedir%\testtoken.txt") do IF /i "%%~nxF" neq "testtoken.txt" (

 REM method 1 - robocopy
 echo(robocopy "%%~dpF." "%destdir%\%%D-%%C-%%B" "%%F" /mov

 REM method 2 - XCOPY
 ECHO(XCOPY "%%F" "%destdir%\%%D-%%C-%%B\"

 REM method 3 - MD and move
 ECHO(MD "%destdir%\%%D-%%C-%%B\"
 ECHO(MOVE "%%F" "%destdir%\%%D-%%C-%%B\"

 ECHO ==================================
)

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the setting of `sourcedir` and `destdir` to suit your circumstances. I've changed the variable names to more descriptive names.

Note: I've reversed the date to yyyy-mm-dd format which sorts more easily than dd-mm-yyyy format. Simply reverse the token order %%D-%%C-%%B if you insist on dd-mm-yyyy.

I prefer method 2 or 3 over `robocopy` so I'm not particularly familiar with `robocopy` syntax. YMMV.

The required MD commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, change `ECHO(MD` to `MD` to actually create the directories. Append `2>nul` to suppress error messages (eg. when the directory already exists)

The required MOVE commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, change `ECHO(MOVE` to `MOVE` to actually move the files.  Append `>nul` to suppress report messages (eg. `1 file moved`)

The required XCOPY commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, change `ECHO(XCOPY` to `XCOPY` to actually copy the files.

The required ROBOCOPY commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, change `ECHO(ROBOCOPY` to `ROBOCOPY` to actually copy the files.

Obviously, choose one of the three methods.

Note that your exclusion of `testtoken.txt` would likely be ineffective since your code targeted short filenames and `testtoken.txt` is the long filename. I'm not sure that `robocopy` would do the exception, but the `if` gate I've implemented certainly will.

Since my date format and your differ, I used your data to test the procedure on my system. Obviously, it seemed to work else I'd not bother posting it.

The token-controls in the `for...%%B` statement re designed to allot day, month and year to %%B,C,D, skip token 4 (time) and %%E is allotted "AM/PM) - used as a dummy. %%F gets the rest of the line, which should be the full filename generated by the `%%~fA` into the listing file.

---

Edited code to remove terminal space being added to `testtoken.txt` lines in response to OP comment.

Comment: The robocopy method doesn't work. I had a look at the robocopy logs, what I found is that instead of calling the robocopy command as: `robocopy "source" "destination" "file to be copied.extension"`, it adds an extra space after "filename.extension" like: `robocopy "source" "destination" "file to be copied.extension "`, which robocopy doesn't recognise

Answer (score 0):

You probably should change the format of your file a bit. Instead of making the extension the last column just use the filename there. You then know that the last token extends to the rest of the line, including any spaces:

```
for /f "tokens=1-5* delims=/ " %A in ("09/11/2014 07:55 PM Test file with spaces.jpg") do (echo %F)
```

As for quoting any paths with spaces I don't spot any glaring issues right now. `for ... in (%_a%\testtoken.txt)` *may* be a problem, which can be solved by using

```
for /f "usebackq <other options>" ... in ("%_a%\testtoken.txt") do ...
```

at least if the documentation can be trusted:

> ```
> usebackq        - specifies that the new semantics are in force,
>                   where a back quoted string is executed as a
>                   command and a single quoted string is a
>                   literal string command and allows the use of
>                   double quotes to quote file names in
>                   file-set.
> ```